# Redefinition of derivative, how to prove the converse, and a question about best affine approximation

Tags: calculus

First, sorry for my bad English, I can understand the language, but writing is harder.

It's known that it's possible to redefine the derivative in one-variable calculus as follows:

> The function $f$ has a derivative if and only if $f(x) = f(x_0) + m(x-x_0) + r(x)(x-x_0)$, where $\lim_{x\to x_0} r(x) = 0$.

I got how to prove the "if" part, as it's simple: one just subtracts $f(x_0)$ from both sides and divides everything by $(x-x_0)$, then when $x$ tends to $x_0$, the Newton quotient goes to m.

Two questions:

1. I don't don't how to prove the converse, so that the theorem will be fully proved (if and only if, showing the definitions are equivalent). Can someone give me a hint, please?
2. Also, I would like to know if seeing the derivative this "redefined" way makes it possible to understand why only if the angular coefficient is $a=f'(x_0)$ then the affine approximation is the best near $x_0$, in the sense that if we have two affine functions, $f_1$ and $f_2$, the first with the slope of the derivative (and passing through $(x_0,f(x_0)$), and the second with other slope (and passing through $(x_0,f(x_0)$ too), then

> $$ \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{f(x) - f_1(x)}{f(x) - f_2(x)} = 0$$

That is, the ratio of the errors go to zero, showing that it's the best approximation.

P.S. I'm not searching for a proof of this (but no problem if it's given), I only want to know if it can be seen/follows easily from the "redefined derivative" there or if it has any relation with it (because I can't see yet).

P.P.S. Sorry again for my bad English!

Comment: Don't worry about your English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. For the "only if" part, do you have a candidate for what the value of $m$ should be? Your *hint* from me comes from the fact that we assume $f$ is differentiable at the point $x_0$.
2. For the second question, with $f_1(x) = f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(x-x_0)$ and $f_2(x) = f(x_0) + A(x-x_0)$ for some $A\ne f'(x_0)$, you can write, for $x\ne x_0$,
   $$
   \frac{f(x)-f_1(x)}{f(x)-f_2(x)} = \frac{r(x)(x-x_0)}{(f'(x_0)-A+r(x))(x-x_0)} = \frac{r(x)}{f'(x_0)-A+r(x)}.
   $$
   Here $r(x)$ is exactly as in the "redefinition" of the derivative you gave. If you let $x\to x_0$ in the last expression, what do you get? Can you see why $A\ne f'(x_0)$ is crucial for what your answer is?

Comment: Thank you very much!